# Proving $F = -(dV)/(dx)$ for conservative forces and application

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy, conventions, conservative-field

How could we prove that $F=-\frac{dV}{dx}$ for conservative forces? I tried to it with:

$W=F\Delta x$

with Work-Energy theorem, we get

$W=\Delta K$

$\Delta K = F \Delta x$

Now from the law of conservation of mechanical energy, we get

$\Delta K + \Delta V = 0$

$F\Delta x + \Delta V=0$

$F\Delta x = -\Delta V$

$F = -\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta x}$

Is that correct? I am still unsure about the sign.

For example, gravitational potential energy is given by $-Gm_1m_2/r$. The derivative would be $Gm_1m_2/r^2$, but then we still need to add the negative sign to it, because $F=-\frac{dV}{dr}$, so it would be $F=-Gm_1m_2/r^2$, which would be wrong. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't really make much sense as you DEFINE a potential function in the context of a line integral. the sign doesn't matter as that is just a matter of what you want you potential function to represent. I'm guessing your main question reworded is:

Given that a function  F, can be written as the gradient of A scalar function, prove that it is a Conservative vector field.

Where Conservative means that the line integral is independent of a path.

so given that we have the line integral of f.dr where f is the grad of a scalar function we now have integral grad v . dr

This is just trivial as you can actually compute the gradient  dot dr  as -  (dv/dx i + dv/dy j + dv/dz j ) . (dx/dt i+dy/dt i+dz/dt i) dt
(where dr is just r'(x,y,z) dt)

so the dot product is just (dv/dx *dx/dt) + (dv/dy * dy/dt)+ (dv/dz *dz/dt) all multiple by dt

This dot product is just simply d/dt( v(x,y,z) where x,y,z are function of t, simply a multi variable.chain rule

so the expression is now just Integral d/dt(v) * dt
which is obviously just V(x,y,z) adding bounds into this just gets you that the line integral is v(a)-v(b) which is only dependant of the start and end and not of the path. thus if f can be written as the gradient of a scalar function then it MUST be Conservative.

now your main confusion is probably why the negative when talking about potentials. this is because our previous line integral that we calculated represented the work done By the field. thus our potential function we calculated in this case represents the work done BY THE FIELD. which actually would mean that f = grad (v) with no negative. however in physics we don't want our potential function to be defined as the work done by the field. we define it as the work done by an external force AGAINST THE FIELD so if we setup our line integral to actually represent this. it would be integral of -f .dr as we are applying a force AGAINST F. doing the same operation as we did for calculating the work done by the field . we get that " assuming the inside equal to the gradient of v" we get V to represent the work done against the field. Well what is this inside function? -f  therefore we set -f to be equal to grad v.  or simply rewritten to be f= - grad v.

Edit:, F =-GMm/r^2 is correct. your confusion as its actually has a r^ attached to it( as its a vector force) which points radially outwards, so the negative means the force points radially inwards aka an attractive force

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to reformat this answer using mathjax.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof, is correct. However, there is easier way to find the proof, based on definition of potential energy. itself.

The change in potnetial energy is defined as negative of work done by conservative forces.

So we have: $$U_f-U_i=-\int_{\vec{r_i}}^{\vec{r_f}}\vec{F_{\text{net}}}d\vec{r}$$

Differnetiating wrt $\vec{r}$:

$$\vec{F_{\text{net}}}=-\dfrac{dU}{d{\vec{r}}}$$

Your doubt about $F=-Gm_1m_2/r$ is acutally correct vectorially. Force cannot have magnitude in negative but here negative sign represents opposite, direction in which ever coordinate frame we thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems fine to me.  You are assuming that there exists some function $V(x)$ such that $E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 + V(x)$ is conserved along trajectories which obey $F = ma$, and then show that $F = -\frac{dV}{dx}$.

> [...] but then we still need to add the negative sign to it, because $F=-\frac{dV}{dr}$, so it would be $F=-Gm_1m_2/r^2$, which would be wrong.

That isn't wrong.  The negative sign means that the gravitational force is attractive.  When we write $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$ (without the minus sign) we are talking about the *magnitude* of the gravitational force.

---

The right way to see this is to use vectors, not the hand-waving quasi-1D approach used in some non-calculus based introductory physics books. If you have a mass $M$ which is fixed to the coordinate origin, then the potential energy of a test mass $m$ which has position vector $\mathbf r$ is given by $V(\mathbf r) = -G M m/|\mathbf r|$.  The force is then given by
$$\mathbf F(\mathbf r) = - \nabla V(\mathbf r) = -\frac{GMm}{|\mathbf r|^2} \hat r$$
where $\nabla V$ is the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of $V$ and $\hat r$ is the unit vector pointing radially **away** from the origin.  The presence of the minus sign means that the force is directed opposite to $\hat r$, i.e. in **towards** the origin, and so the force is an attractive one.